# Expected Lifetime: Churn Formula vs. Experience Data

Tags: churn

I am analyzing data for a subscription based company. I.e they sell a service in exchange for monthly payment. I would like to conduct an analysis and come up with an estimate of the average lifetime (in months) of a customer. I have approximately 6 years of data including date of enrollment and date of cancellation. N is fairly large 70k, 80k, 100k, 115k, 135k, 161k enrolled clients in the 6 years, respectively.

I have seen articles such as [this one](https://www.clv-calculator.com/using-the-retention-rate-to-calculate-average-lifetime-period/) that describe how to calculate average lifetime by taking $$\frac{1}{\text{churn rate}} = \frac{1}{\text{1-retention rate}}.$$

I don't entirely understand *why* this formula holds,but my understanding is that this is a problistic calculation. Someone on my team calculated an average lifetime of 71 months using this methodology.

Out of curiosity, I wanted to compare this to our experience, so I computed the following in R

```
data %>%
  filter(Cancelled == "TRUE") %>%  #--ignore active policies 
  mutate(duration = 12*(as.yearmon(CancelRequestDate) - as.yearmon(EnrollDate))) %>%
  pull(duration) %>%
  mean()
 
> dataAvgPetMo
  24.52419
```

These two numbers are very different. Could anyone enlighten me as to why, and perhaps offer some guidance for how to interpret or refine this study to come up with a reasonable estimate of average lifetime.

---

new to this community. edits and advice welcome :)

Comment: To me it makes completely sense to calculate 1/churn_rate since, where churn_rate is the probability given by a classification model of the customer to cancel the policy. When this probability tends to 0 that value will tend to infinity and will tend to 0 when probablity tends to 1. I'm thinking you could use this difference (1/churn_rate) - 12*(as.yearmon(CancelRequestDate) - as.yearmon(EnrollDate))) as metric for you model

Comment: 1. Is the 71 initially mentioned, also calculated in non-cancelled policies? 2.Is churn rate the probability of a customer to cancel at what moment? (1, 2,3 months after?) That would change the interpretation on your validation vs 1/churn_rate 3. If your target is to predict the months from enrolldat and cancelldate why not to use this as the target for a regression model?

Answer (score 0):

The average lifetime is calculated simply by using the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)'s mean formula. If probability of churn in any month (or simply percent churned in a month) is 0.2, then the expected life time of a customer is 1/0.2 = 5 months.

Here you are filtering the unchurned customer at the first step (`filter(Cancelled == "TRUE")`) and therefore you get the average lifetime of the churned customers in your sample rather than the average lifetime of any customer.